# Connect to SQL Server 2008 Database via C#

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, permissions, database-connection, ssms

I am attempting to connect to a database I created in SQL Server 2008 on my computer.
I have a Windows Authentication login which looks like this:

```
try
{
  string sCon = @"Data Source=David-PC\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog=ZarTrackDB; Integrated Security = true";
   SqlConnection dbConn;
   dbConn = new SqlConnection(sCon);
   dbConn.Open();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(this, "An error occurd while attemtpting to connect to DB.\n" + ex.Message, "DB Connection Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
     return;
}
```

however it keeps throwing an exception:

> Login failed for user David-PC\David

I am able to connect to the Master DB though:

```
 string sCon = @"Data Source=David-PC\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog=Master; Integrated Security = true";
```

So i guess the probelm might be I do not have permissions? How do I go about giving myslef permissions to access this DB though when I login via SQL Server Management Studio I can insert create query etc on the ZarTrackDB perfectly.

I truly dont know what to do anymore please help!

EDIT:

here is a screen shot of my user mappings for the account I am trying to log in with:

**User Mappings:**

[image]

**Server Roles**:

[image]

UPDATE:

If I login to master and attempt to access ZarTrack :

```
   string sCon = @"Data Source=David-PC\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog=Master; Integrated Security = true";
                SqlConnection dbConn;
                dbConn = new SqlConnection(sCon);
                dbConn.Open();

                string sql = "USE ZarTrackDB "+
"CREATE TABLE Customers ("+

"CustomerID int IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL," +
"CompanyName varchar(30) NOT NULL,"+
"CompanyAddress varchar(40) NOT NULL,"+
"Email varchar(40) NOT NULL,"+
"PhoneNumber varchar(15) NOT NULL"+
");";
                SqlCommand dbCmd = new SqlCommand();
                dbCmd.CommandText = sql;
                dbCmd.Connection = dbConn;

                dbCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

I get Exception:

[image]

Comment: Use SQL Server Management Studio and look at the `Security` nodes for the database and server. Make sure there is a login and an associated User and that this user has the right permissions on the database.

Comment: @Oded Where are the security nodes for database and server ( I only see a secruirty tree that has Logins Server Roles etc)? Im sorry for sounding noob like. And how would I associate my current Login with the permissions needed?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337552.aspx

Comment: Have you added your user to the database? Are you using SQL server 2008 or SQL express?

Comment: @maralfol Wel I just installed SQL Express and my windows account was used as the default Windows Authentication login

Comment: @Oded +1 thanks will take a lokk

Comment: Have you try to change this "Initial Catalog=Master" and point to ZarTrackDB?

Comment: I'm not sure about your error but, how about "Data Source=David-PC\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog=ZarTrackDB; Integrated Security = true" and remove your "USE ZarTrackDB". I always do that by this way. I never needed to use the master as a initial catalog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the

> David-PC\SQLEXPRESS

was the problem when I do:

```
string sCon = @"Data Source=David-PC; Initial Catalog=ZarTrackDB; Integrated Security = true";
SqlConnection dbConn;
dbConn = new SqlConnection(sCon);
dbConn.Open();
```

It works perfectly

Comment: This should be because you have installed it as anonymous (or default) instance.